# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' when comparing file names

Tags: python, list, replace, glob

I want to combine information from two files in different directories that have similar names, but not entirely. For this, I thought I'd write an if loop that checks if the file names are similar at the end and contain the right information to continue with the rest of the code. I tried the following code:

```
import glob

GO_list=glob.glob('/home/anna/Inputs/*')
ID_list=glob.glob('/home/anna/data/ID/*')

for go in GO_list:
    for id in ID_list:
            if go.replace('/Inputs/','').replace('_GO_enrich','').replace('_Revigo','')[-20:] == id.replace('/data/ID/','').replace('_ensid','')[-20:]:
```

Unfortunately, that gives me the error stated in the title.
To check if somehow the file names are lists or that replacing elements turns them into a list I printed the following:

```
print type(go)
print type(go.replace('/Inputs/','').replace('_GO_enrich','').replace('_Revigo','')[-20:])
print type(idag)
print type(idag.replace('/data/ID/','').replace('_ensid','')[-20:])
```

These all printed:
    type 'str'

Another thing I tried was replacing the if statement by either of the following:

```
if go.replace('/Inputs/','').replace('_GO_enrich','').replace('_Revigo','')[-20:] == 'test':

if id.replace('/data/ID/','').replace('_ensid','')[-20:] == 'test':
```

Those didn't give an error message.

Does anyone know where Python is seeing the list and how I can change it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tries printing the content of variable on which you are calling `.replace()`? As the error says, it is of list type and `.replace()` is present for string type

Comment: Can you post the entire stack please?

Comment: @ kabanus; what do you mean with the entire stack?